# Give a label to a repeating sequence of numbers.

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data.frame with repeating values of unequal length, and the maximum sequence length is 6.

```
location = c(1:6, 1:4, 1:6, 1:3) 
data.frame(location = location)
```

> ```
>    location
> 1      1
> 2      2
> 3      3
> 4      4
> 5      5
> 6      6
> 7      1
> 8      2
> 9      3
> 10     4
> 11     1
> 12     2
> 13     3
> 14     4
> 15     5
> 16     6
> 17     1
> 18     2
> 19     3
> ```

How would I assign a label to each of the groups like the following:

> ```
>  location     batch
> 1      1  a
> 2      2  a
> 3      3  a
> 4      4  a
> 5      5  a
> 6      6  a
> 7      1  b
> 8      2  b
> 9      3  b
> 10     4  b
> 11     1  c
> 12     2  c
> 13     3  c
> 14     4  c
> 15     5  c
> 16     6  c
> 17     1  d
> 18     2  d
> 19     3  d
> ```

Comment: Are there more than 26 groups?

Comment: Oh yes there are. Any grouping variable is fine with me!

Comment: Do the "location" group values always start with 1?

Comment: In this case, yes, they all start with 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an numeric grouping variable in the following way:

```
dat$batch <- c(0L, cumsum(diff(dat$location) < 1))


   location batch
1         1     0
2         2     0
3         3     0
4         4     0
5         5     0
6         6     0
7         1     1
8         2     1
9         3     1
10        4     1
11        1     2
12        2     2
13        3     2
14        4     2
15        5     2
16        6     2
17        1     3
18        2     3
19        3     3
```

Comment: You might need to do `c(1,....) < 1` for the case were there is only 1 location in the group.

Answer (score 1):

If "location" groups always start with 1, then it's even more straightforward than Sven's answer: Just use `cumsum` on the logical vector that results when you use `==`.

```
location <- c(1:6, 1:4, 1:6, 1:3)
dat <- data.frame(location = location)
dat$batch <- cumsum(dat$location == 1)
dat
#    location batch
# 1         1     1
# 2         2     1
# 3         3     1
# 4         4     1
# 5         5     1
# 6         6     1
# 7         1     2
# 8         2     2
# 9         3     2
# 10        4     2
# 11        1     3
# 12        2     3
# 13        3     3
# 14        4     3
# 15        5     3
# 16        6     3
# 17        1     4
# 18        2     4
# 19        3     4
```